# How to Insert entity to DB via Context with multiple relationships?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, insert, repository

```
public Tournament Create(Tournament entity)
{
    using (var context = new DragonLairContext())
    {
        context.Games.Attach(entity.Game);
        context.Genres.Attach(entity.Game.Genre);
        context.TournamentTypes.Attach(entity.TournamentType);
        context.Tournaments.Add(entity);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
    return entity;
}
```

The tournament entity from the parameter contains a lot of data.

`entity` has many `groups`

`entity.Groups` has many `Teams`

`entity.Groups.Teams` has many `players`

`Groups` and `teams` are autogenerated and is not in the db.  `Players` is already known to the database.

Note that games, genres and tournamenttypes work fine.

My problem is that after closing the context, it will create multiple groups, teams and players - and it is the same entities added many times.

Any ideas guys? Can't figure this one out

Cheers

[Before saving context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcagJ.png)

[After saving context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNAZN.png)

Comment: Can you attach your DB mapping configurations for those entities? If mapping is done correctly, calling context.Tournaments.Add(entity); and context.SaveChanges(); should be more than enough.

Comment: Hi @raderick, in the tournament entity I have a public virtual List<Group> Groups { get; set; } - and the same thing in the group entity. I haven't used  fluent api

Comment: and so goes for the rest of the entities

Comment: How do groups, teams and players come to your entity properties? Do you load them beforehands in a separate context and then pass to the method? In this case, they are not attached to your "DragonLairContext context" and are re-attached again when you save Tournament entities, because this method context has no track of them

Comment: I get them from an Ui. I attach entity.game, entity.game.genre and tournament.tournamenttype because theyre already on the database. The players are also in the database, but I'm not sure how to attach them.

Comment: Then you should somehow query your DB to get your teams/players. In your specific case you should receive team ids from your UI and query for them in your DB, and assign to your Tournament.Teams property